# How can I use the grunt-express for express 4.12?

Tags: express, gruntjs, grunt-express

I use the Express 4.12 to build my project and I want to use [grunt-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-express) to start my application. I have known that Express 4.12 start the application via node ./bin/www, so I write the Gruntfile.js like this:

```
express: {
  dev: {
    options: {
      port: 3000,
      bases: path.resolve('bin/'),
      server: path.resolve('bin/www')
    }
  }
}

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-express')
grunt.registerTask('default', ['express', 'express-keepalive']);
```

Unfortunately, when I run grunt, it reports an error:

```
Fatal error: Server should provide a function called "listen" that acts as http.Server.listen
```

But I found that in the www file, there is a function "listen":

```
var server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(port);
```

I am confused about this. Could you please teach me write the Gruntfile.js
for the www file?

Answer (score 1):

The `grunt-express` server option expects to see an express app, which is not what `bin/www` is. If you look at `bin/www`, what is it requiring for an express app? Eg, it should be an `app.js` in your project root, or maybe it would be `server/index.js`.

Also, your `bases` probably shouldn't be `bin`, rather it should be pointing to a public static resources dir, eg `/public` or if you have a build step that generates minified stuff it might be `/dist`.

Try this (editing server and bases to match your project):

```
grunt.initConfig({
    express: {
        options: {
            port: 3000,
            hostname: 'localhost'
        },
        dev: {
            options: {
                server: path.resolve('./app.js'),
                bases: [path.resolve('./public')]
            }
        }
    }
});
```