# Grunt-express and static routes : Server should provide a function called "listen" that acts as http.Server.listen

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, grunt-express

I am trying to set-up Grunt to start my express server, using grunt-express.
After reading the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-express) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559774/how-can-i-use-the-grunt-express-for-express-4-12), I still can't figure it out. I've tried several combinations for my Grunt file.
Nonetheless, each time I'm getting the *Server should provide a function called "listen" that acts as http.Server.listen* error

Here is my code :

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    'use strict';

    var path = require('path');

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        app: {
            basePath: 'public',
            [...],
            serverPath: 'backend'
        },

        express: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    port: 3000,
                    hostname:  '*', //()=>Localhost
                    bases: '<%= app.basePath %>',
                    server: '<%= app.serverPath %>/Server.js',
                    livereload: true
                }
            }              
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('server', [
        'express',
        'open',
        'watch'
    ]);
    };
```

Project structure :

```
App_Root/
  -Backend/
   --Server.js
   --BackofficeRouter.js
  -Public/
   --index.html
```

Server.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var backofficeRouter = require('./backofficeRouter.js');
var constants = require('./../public/constants/ConstantsModule.js');
var app = express();
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');

app.use('/backoffice', backofficeRouter);
app.use(express.static(appRoot + '/public'));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

BackofficeRouter.js :

```
backofficeRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(appRoot + '/public/index.html'));
});
```

I don't really get how grunt-express interacts with my Server.js file.
I've tried to set the default grunt-express config in my Gruntfile, thinking it would take into account what I have in my Server.js. But it seems like grunt-express' config overrides everything.
Any hints on where I could have made a mistake ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: it looks as if you should be exporting app and not call listen from the server script (just a guess)

Comment: Do you mean exporting my Server.js as a module ?

Comment: I mean exporting your configured instance of express (i.e. app) as a module. My assumption is that if your error says it's looking for a 'listen' method, you should probably be giving the caller a module that contains that method, which in this case would be app.

Comment: @ruedamanuel, Thanks that did the trick !! I was thinking that grunt launched the actual server using a commend similar to node myfile.js. Didn't understand at all that it needed an actual instance of the file. Neat !

Comment: np, glad it worked, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Server should provide a function called "listen" that acts as http.Server.listen* error suggests that the grunt task is expecting a server instance that contains the method 'listen', so you should remove this line from your server

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

and replace it for

```
module.exports = app;
```

that way, the grunt task will receive a configured instance of express that contains the listen method it is looking for.